# The certificate's CN name does not match the passed value

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate, uwp

I am trying to connect  to a remote server using a secure StreamSocket so when I try to connect I get an exception

```
  Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.Certificate certificate = await GetClientCert();
        socket.Control.ClientCertificate = certificate;
        await socket.ConnectAsync(new Windows.Networking.HostName(SocksParameters.Host), SocksParameters.Port, SocketProtectionLevel.Tls12);
```

Why i am getting this exception when i try to ConnectAsync() and how can i avoid this? Please help me because  i am in desperate position

```
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The certificate's CN name does not match the passed value. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800B010F)
```

Comment: Is SocksParameters.Host an FQDN and does it match the subject of the server certificate?

Comment: Can y be more Specific

Comment: Check the value of SocksParameters.Host that you're passing to ConnectAsync, then validate that is an FQDN (e.g. mail.google.com), then make sure that it matches the server certificate subject value (e.g. CN=mail.google.com)

Comment: SocksParameters.Host = "192.168.1.68" it connect and throws error .inThe backent which is written in node.js

Comment: Try changing SocksParameters.Host to match the certificate subject name (i.e. CN name) in the server certificate.